# How can I batch format string attributes in a CSV file?

Tags: string, csv, edit, batch-processing

So I have a csv file of around 15,000 rows. I only need to edit one of the 10 columns which is a Postcode. None of the columns have headers. It is currently in the format 'AB101AA' which I need to change to 'AB10 1AA'.

First off, is there a method for which I can do this for every row?

Then it gets more complicated in that Postcodes vary in format to these four types;

- 'A1 1AA',
- 'A10 1AA',
- 'AB1 1AA' and
- 'AB10 1AA'.

What I'm trying to do is to find a way to run through every row and first of all test the format to check whether it is as above and then edit if needs be, to force that space.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Only with a batch file? Or is Powershell or vbscript allowed, too?

Answer (score 0):

How about opening it in Excel, then

- Use a formula to add a column which takes the first `LENGTH(A1)-3` characters, a space, and the last three characters (copy/paste, or drag the + on the lower right corner of the cell, to make sure the formula is replicated in every row of that new column)
- Copy the extra column
- Paste the values over the original column
- Delete the extra column